# QUERY in ARRAYFORMULA to FILTER, JOIN and LEN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given a table like this one:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tese | (2021/039-07964) | (8146.000336/2021-60) | Tema 1092 |  |
| 2 | Afetado |  |  | Tema 1092 | Controvérsia 251 |

```
|3|Tese|(2021/0390796-6)||Tema 1093|Controvérsia 258|
|4|Afetado|||Tema 1093|Controvérsia 258|
|5|Tese|(2021/0390796-7)|(8146.000338/2021-50)||Controvérsia 238|
```

As long strings in Col A's rows are equal to "Tese", Col F should return a string (with line breaks) that compiles Col B to D strings that are not null in the same row.

So, row 1 of Col F should be:

| F |
| --- |
| (2021/0390796-4) (8146.000336/2021-60) Tema 1092 |

Row 2 of Col F should be:

| F |
| --- |
| (2021/039-07966) Tema 1093 Controvérsia 258 |

And so on

I'm using a dropdown formula to do the job, which is working fine:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1="Tese",JOIN(CHAR(10),FILTER(B1:E1, LEN(B1:E1))),""))
```

But it would be easier if it could be replaced by an array formula (the table is over 4,000 rows!).

I think it is possible to use a query, but I could not write the formula down.

The real table is here: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VDn7oLxd0KDw2jXukom-c03qs3ErxRJNToJmcYroXKk/edit#gid=306985279)

Comment: duplicate question?

Comment: Although there are some common elements with a previous question, this is a different one.

Comment: By the way, could anyone help me to fix the table problem in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear all contents of column G and try in G1

```
={"Informações completa da tese"; INDEX(IF(A2:A="Tese"; SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:F; " "; "$"));;ROWS(A2:A)))); " "; char(10)); "$"; " ");))}
```

See if that helps?

[image]